# CSS Drop Down menus don't appear in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

In my web site at:
http://www.mensdiscipleshipnetwork.com

I have pure CSS drop down menus. They seem to work with Internet Explorer 8 and 9, but in IE7 the drop down menus don't appear at all. I changed the z-index to 1000 on the div where the navbar resides, however, it still doesn't work. I saw from another similar question someone suggested applying the z-index to the ul tag. This did not work either. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, I read that as Mens' Disciples Hip Network...

Comment: :) That's great! I have to tell my friends at the ministry that one!

Comment: I'm not sure. But that shouldn't impact the fact that the menus are not even visible in the mouse out position, should it?

Comment: @chovy: No it doesn't as far as I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different solution which does not involve z-index, such as one of the following:

- [float-drop menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/float-drop-multi-column.html)
- [time dropdown menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/html-plus-time-dropdown-menu.html)
- [time flyout menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/css-time-flyout.html)